# How do I host a Node.js app on a subdomain from an apache2 VPS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express, vps

So, I have a Node.js app and I want to host it on a subdomain using my VPS. My VPS is currently running apache2 and my Node.js app uses Express. I have tried [Phusion](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/ownserver/apache/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html) and have also tried [this](https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/nodejs/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/) tutorial with no luck. Also, my app uses Puppeteer which I'm not sure it makes a difference. I'm new to servers and web development so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can host the production-grade application with the help of Nginx & PM2 (node process manager) Instead of apache, you can give a try to Nginx since most of the NodeJS or Express application use NGINX as an HTTP proxy front of PM2. You need to do reverse proxy of your domain to `localhost:<port>`

Sample Nginx vhost,

```
server {
   server_name application.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://<private-ip>:<port>;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

For setting up [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/).
Install this process manager globally. For more reference you can check it [here](https://medium.com/today-i-learned-chai/setup-node-js-application-with-pm2-and-nginx-72840f44ea73)

Comment: This should be an Apache focus solution. Not a suggestion to switch to another server infrastructure.